# Render object don't show in certain area

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

This lock of hair does not appear on the renderer in this particular place on the head.

Besides this no new lock of hair in this place on the head appears on the renderer also, but it is necessary to move it to another hair part above the head and the lock becomes visible.

How to fix this?

In preview you can see it, but in the render only a black stripe from the hair under the skin and in the part of head all mesh are invisible.

[image]

Comment: anyone? someone?

Comment: maybe share your file (remove all the useless parts)? https://pasteall.org/blend/